# should I prefer gulp-inject or wiredep

Tags: angularjs, gulp, mean-stack, wiredep, gulp-inject

I am getting myself used to task runners. When working with `gulp`, I found out that there are two plug-ins, `gulp-inject` and `wiredep`.

I understand that they are two things which do the same thing. Am I correct? If not, Can someone please explain it to me the differences between those two and the respective scenario's to use one and the other.

Comment: I don't think you even need `gulp-inject` here. You can just use `fs.readFileSync(filePath)` to inject one file content to another. I don't know about `wiredep`.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

gulp-inject does a great job at selecting all your javascript and css files, while wiredep assists with selecting the right files from any installed bower packages.

So if you are using "bower" in your projects, wiredep might sound like a better choice, otherwise gulp-inject will do just fine for you.